# Stuck with SQL query "select from table where column "

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a query for a very small task. for example: I have two column "Name" and "Cash", here is some sample data:

```
Cash     Name
100      mr. A
110      mr. A
150      mr. A
120      mr. A
200      mr. B
220      mr. B
202      mr. B
300      mr. C
```

Now I need to make a query for 220(Cash) which will search the full database,
I was try lite that;

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_cash` 
WHERE `cash`='220' AND `name` = 'mr. B' OR `name` = 'mr. A' OR `name` = 'mr. C'
```

But it's not work. As I need to search the full database for match name and cash and then it should output the correct value.

Comment: just use IN query with group by "SELECT * FROM tbl_cash WHERE cash='220' AND name IN('mr. A', 'mr. B', 'mr. C') GROUP BY cash, name

Comment: i will never help php,mysql peoples, to get competition they downvoted each others, my 8 points are downvoted without any reason

Answer (score 3):

try this- use the `IN` operator, it allows you to specify multiple values in a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_cash` 
WHERE `cash`='220' AND `name` IN ('mr. B','mr. A','mr. C')
```

Answer (score -2):

you mean

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_cash WHERE cash='220'
```

or

```
 SELECT * FROM `tbl_cash` WHERE cash='220' AND (name = 'mr. B' OR name = 'mr. A' OR name = 'mr. C')
```

or

```
 SELECT * FROM `tbl_cash` WHERE cash='220' AND (name like 'mr.%')
```

Answer (score -2):

Simply try using `IN` operator as

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_cash` 
WHERE `cash`='220' AND `name` IN('mr. B','mr. A','mr. C')
```

Answer (score -2):

use this one

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_cash WHERE cash='220' AND name IN('mr. A', 'mr. B', 'mr. C') GROUP BY cash, name
```

Answer (score -2):

SELECT * FROM `tbl_cash` 
    WHERE `cash`=220 AND `name` LIKE 'mr.%')`